# Linker error after upgrading solution to VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, upgrade, project-setup

I was developing a project that uses (among others) `boost::filesystem` under `VS2010`. Today I decided to switch to `VS2012`, upgraded the solution (just let the VS do it automatically) and when I tried to compile it seems all went fine except for 1 thing:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc100-mt-gd-1_53.lib'
```

I keep `boost` in a separate folder (outside the project location), the paths seems to be correct (I have precompiled `*.lib` files of `boost`, both for `VS2010` and `VS2012`). The error suggests the project looks for the old versions of libs (`vc100` instead of `vc110`) but I have no idea how to change that.

Comment: Is the [platform toolset](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) set to `v110`?

Comment: ... No, it wasn't. I thought "solution upgrade" should take care of that but apparently I was wrong. Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @NPS IIRC, when upgrading a solution VS pops up a dialog box asking whether you want the projects upgraded to the latest platform toolset. Maybe you dismissed the dialog accidentally.

Comment: @drescherjm No, it isn't. And, **as I said**, my library and include settings are correct.

Comment: @drescherjm I'm not sure what you are talking about, the problem is fixed, I didn't notice the `Platform Toolset` was set to `v100` instead of `v110`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I misread and thought you were going the other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the [Platform Toolset](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/12/08/c-native-multi-targeting.aspx) option is set to `v110`. Right click on the project name and select *Properties*. Then under *Configuration Properties* -> *General* -> *Platform Toolset* select *Visual Studio 2012 (v110)*.